# C# regex to match text string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use a regex to find text inside a string. For example, have this string:

```
one,two,three,four
```

If I want to see if it has one OR two, I can use "one|two". How do I create a regex for determining whether the string has one AND two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\bone\b)(?=.*\btwo\b)
```

= two lookahead assertions that match if both "one" and "two" are present in the string.

Comment: Nice, wouldn't of thought to use lookaheads for that... I would add a `\b` around `one` and `two` to ensure that `onetwo` isn't matched...

Comment: +1, it would also be useful to add `^` in the beginning to avoid extra work in case of no-match